# WP Get current category URL without parameters

Tags: wordpress, url, parameters, extract

I want current URL without parameters.

Example :

I have this

```
http://www.localhost/ajr/gadget/?tri=prix&order=desc
```

I want only this

```
http://www.localhost/ajr/gadget/
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: You must change the logic of this page/plugin and use POST calls instead of GET calls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I ever use post 
    <option value="?tri=prix&order=asc" method="POST">Moins cher</option>
    <option value="?tri=prix&order=desc" method="POST">Plus cher</option>

Answer (score 9):

Why not use:

```
$current_url = strtok($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], '?');
```

Its neat bacause It **always** returns a string, (not `true` or `false`) without `?` and stuff behind `?`

Another url, not current url:

```
$some_url = strtok($some_url, '?');
```

Answer (score 0):

`<option value="?tri=prix&order=asc" method="POST">` makes no sense but if you are getting to this page using the form somewhere, you can send the variables as hidden inputs like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='tri' value='prix'>
<input type='hidden' name='order' value='desc'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reply but I found the solution

```
<?php $current_url = 'http://';
$current_url .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; // Get host
$path = explode( '?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ); // Blow up URI
$current_url .= $path[0]; // Only use the rest of URL - before any parameters
echo $current_url;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function getWpCurrentUrl()
    {
        $url = get_permalink();
        $params = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == '' ? '' : '?' . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

        return $url . $params;
    }
```

or use this method to get current URL without parameters :

```
get_permalink();
```